# Plotting average shows (log) linear trend but fitting line has 0 p value

Tags: regression, binning

I have some data and I am examining the relationship between two variables. When I form x-bins and take summary statistics of y in those bins, I see the plot below. The black line is the mean of each bin, the blue line is the median of each bin and the ranges are the lower and upper quartiles of the bins.

[image: average data plot]

Here is a histogram of all my y values:

[image]

When I do linear regression with scipy.stats.linregress I get intercept -1.21, slope 1.69, r value .21 and p value 0. I think the slope and intercept sort of check out, but how do I interpret the pvalue of 0?

Comment: Remember that he p-value in this type of analysis is reported for a [test of the null hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_hypothesis_testing): the hypothesis that there is _no_ linear relationship between _y_ and _x_.

Comment: So if p was 1, that would mean I could reject the hypothesis with very high confidence that there is no linear relationship between x and y? p being 0 here means I have no confidence that there is not no linear relationship? Can you offer any guidance for how I could interpret the binned statistics vs the linear regression?

Answer (score 1):

The *p* value in this case is the probability that you would find *at least this big* a linear relationship between $y$ and $x$ in a data sample of your size if, in fact, there was *no* such relationship (and the assumptions behind the test hold). So a *p* value of approximately 0 under that null hypothesis means that there is essentially *no* chance that there is *no* linear relationship: in other words, very strong evidence for some linear relationship. Your very large number of data points plays a big role in that conclusion.

In this particular case, the binning has shown further information that you might want to explore.

First, the strictly linear relationship seems to tail off at high absolute values of $x$ at both extremes. If you have a theoretical basis from your knowledge of the subject matter for why that would be the case, you could try a further transformation of the $x$ values in a linear regression, or a non-linear model of appropriate form, to deal with those extremes. Alternatively, if you have no theoretical basis for a particular form, you could use linear regression with spline terms to find an empirically based fit better than simply linear.

Second, the higher median than mean $y$ value in all of your bins suggests that the residuals between observed and predicted values might not have the normal distribution that is assumed in the calculation of *p* values. With this large a data set and this strong a relationship that shouldn't pose a practical problem, but it's something that might be important for other reasons in your application.

Comment: Thanks for answering! I would upvote it if I had more reputation. So my response to @Edm's comment is incorrect? The low p value actually means there *is* a linear relationship?

Comment: @GregoryStarr your response to my comment on your question was incorrect. A low p value for the test of the null hypothesis (no linear relationship) is evidence in favor of a linear relationship here. That’s how these types of statistical tests work: you estimate the probability that you’d get that strong an apparent relationship by chance even if there wasn’t really one.

Comment: Thanks for the help!